# migrate command on laravel 5.1 console

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1, database-migration

I have created many tables use migration file, but I have dropped some table via the mysql command line tool, then I find the migration status about the tables I have dropped is still ran, so how can i fix it?

When I use migrate command, it always says nothing to migrate, but I have no table in my database.

I have tried to delete all the logs and stuff under the storage path.

I have also tried to delete the migration table on mysql or change .env file to use a new database, but both cannot work. Can anyone help me?

I use laravel 5.1.

Comment: Once try with another database.

Comment: Can you provide some of the input and output of the migrations?  Your question isn't entirely clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
`Run migrate:rollback (to undo the last migration)

If migrate:rollback doesn't work ; do it manually:
step 1 : delete the migration file
step 2 : composer dump-autoload (for resetting autoload file)
step 3 : remove the last entry from migration(to modify your database)`
```

> The reason you are not able to migrate although you dont have existing tables in database is because your previous migrations still exist. Either clear the history or perform the above steps

Comment: I have deleteted all the migration files and recreated them, then use migrate command to create tables, lots of migration files.....I just wonder how laravel tell which have ran and which not? It seems nothing to do with the migration table on database. thanks anyway~